# Laravel 8: Call to a member function middleware() on null

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-8

I just made a new Route Group for my project that goes like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::resource('/movies', App\Http\Controllers\MovieController::class);
})->middleware('auth');
```

And I wanted to add `auth` middleware but I get this error:

**Call to a member function middleware() on null**

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion with me on this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should code it like this:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function() {
     Route::resource('/movies', App\Http\Controllers\MovieController::class);
});
```